# Instagram-api error while exchanging code for access token

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm using instagram-api for about 4 month, but recently when i try to do the solution explained [here](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) in python-instagram-api I face an error !

```
CONFIG = {
    'client_id' : 'CLIENT_ID_HERE',
    'client_secret': 'CLIENT_SECRET_HERE',
    'redirect_uri' : 'URI_HERE',
}

api = client.InstagramAPI(**CONFIG)

// Redirect user to instgaram login page and get code
api.exchange_code_for_access_token(code)
```

Error:

```
OAuth2AuthExchangeError at /en/reg_insta/
You must provide a client_id
```

It not appear when i try to do it as explained in [Instagram  site](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/):

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

What is the problem? Has Instagram changed recently?
Any help will appriciated.

Comment: Same problem here and we just don't have a clue about what's happening :-/

Comment: the problem seems to be on the other side of the socket...

Comment: I'm using c#, not python, but i had this exact same problem.  I switched the C#framework helper I was using to make the POST call from WebClient to HttpClient, and that fixed the problem.  So there was something particular about the older client's form post that Instagram didn't like.